# Display modal over a React Class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a simple modal that I want to pop up after button click, but i hav a display problem.
I am using it in Offer.js component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './Offer.scss';

import Modal from '../../common/Modal/Modal';

class Offer extends Component {
  state = {
    showModal: false,
  };

  openModal = () => {
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
    console.log('modal');
  };
  closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  };
  render() {
    const { showModal } = this.state;
    return (
      <section className='Offer'>
        <div className='Offer__Container'>
          <div className='Offer__Content'>
            <div className='Offer__Content-text'>
              <h3>Tadeusz</h3>
              <p>
                Wreszcie po całym domu dawne obyczaje swe rodzinne duszę
                utęsknioną
              </p>
              <button
                onClick={() => this.openModal()}
                className='btn btn-offer'>
                Więcej
              </button>
            </div>
            <Modal show={showModal} close={() => this.closeModal()} />
          </div>
        </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Offer;
```

As you can see I am putting my  after my  with content. but this i casung an issue and right now my modal is just display next to my content

[![Modal show][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX0d9.png

I want it to be showing over my component not next to  with content. I don't want to use hooks as this is just simple componontet and it is for learning purpose.

Comment: Position the modal absolutely and give it a high z-index.

Comment: @shivetay if you want just to solve it with CSS use position absolute, if you want to solve it the react way have a look at react portals

Comment: Thanks. I will try css positiong and take a closer look on portals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, the issue with modals in React is that components can get very deeply nested so you will have problems if you try to render it from a child component as you want to render it above the parent component.

In this case, you could just use CSS tricks to overcome this and set the `z-index` to be a high value and maybe `position: fixed;` or `position: absolute;` with `top: 0;` and `left: 0;` depending on what you're going for.

A better method would be to use React Portals which allows you to render a component outside your current DOM hierarchy. I wrote a tutorial on how to do this [here](https://medium.com/swlh/building-modals-in-react-64d92591f4b)